# CURL canceling request, Does not giving any response

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, angular1.6

I am using angular 1. I am getting data with angular get from back end. My back end function have CURL request which is fetching data from 3rd party server.

In some scenarios it fetches the data i.e. When third party server respond with in 10 to 20 seconds.

The issue is when third party server take 30 seconds or above time. It automatically cancel the request.Image is attached. [image: Cancel request image]

I have also increased the Curl timeout and connection timeout options. But it doesn't work.

here is my code look like

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $radius_url,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "content-type: application/json",
            ),
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 60,
        ));
```

In case of issue it does not even allow to code below that curl request to run. It does not printing any thing below this request in case of issue.

I am using CodeIgniter framework.

Comment: That cancellation is happening on the client-side code. Server-side timeouts have a response code associated with them

Comment: @apokryfos that completely depends on what's doing the timeout.

Comment: @apokryfos So you are saying it is from client side not from server side?

Comment: yes, cancelled comes from the browser cancelling the request for some reason. Try setting the timeout setting in angular to confirm whether that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set your servers timeout limit to

```
 set_time_limit(0);
```

If its still continues there may be a time out in the service's server. You can contact their support.

Answer (score 0):

It look like php timeout

you have two solution.

It's all the time to improve the execution time of PHP

one.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time=30
```

change max_execution_time too large

and two.

you add first  code

set_time_limit(0)